# Page-wide Image in a two-column scrbook layout

Tags: graphics, sectioning, two-column, scrbook

In a document based on scrbook class and setup with twocolumn, I need to place an image that spans the textwidth.
In the below example, using just the {figure*} environment and a 590px by 350px simple white image, it works, UNLESS there's a \chapter too close to the figure, then the text gets pushed to a new page and the image ends up all by itself on a blank page.

So, to sum up once more, I need it to work like it does in the MWE (image and text on one page), but do so even when I use /chapter nearby.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.4in, left=1.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}
\caption{This is a tiger.}
\end{figure*}
%\chapter*{2nd Chapter}
\lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In most classes `\chapter` does a `\cleardoublepage` to flush all floats to stop them drifting from one chapter to the next. That puts any pending floats on a float page. If you want the float to arrive on a text page before the chapter you need to move it earlier in the source file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.